# Prove the existence of a bijection

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets, and suppose $A$ is infinite.
Let $B$ be a countably infinite subset of $A$.

Show that if $f: \mathbb{N} \to B$ and $g: B \to \mathbb{N}$ are bijections, then
$$
h: A \to A- \{ f(1) \}, \, a \mapsto
\begin{cases}
  a, & \text{if $a \notin B$} \\
  f(1+g(a)), & \text{if $a \in B$ }
\end{cases},
$$
is also a bijection.

I am not really sure how to do this one

Comment: what does $A - f(1)$ mean. Is that the set $A$ kick out $f(1)$?

Comment: And are we proving $h$ is a bijection?

Comment: And why is this tagged number theory?

Comment: yes set A without f(1) and I want to prove h is bijective.

Comment: @Meer what have you tried so far? Have you tried showing h is injective, or surjective?

Comment: so far in my book i have only seen something like f(n) = 5n + 3 is injective and not surjective.. and suddenly I saw this and am lost..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show injectivity, assume that $h(x) = h(y)$ for some $x,y \in A$. We want to show that $x = y$. There are a few cases:

Case 1 ($x,y \in B$): Then by definition $h(x) = x$ and $h(y) = y$. So we have $x = y$.

Case 2 ($x,y \notin B$): Then we have that $f(1+g(x)) = f(1+g(y))$. Since both $f,g$ are invertible, we have that $x = y$.

Case 3 ($x \in B$, $y \notin B$): Then $h(x) \in B$ since $f(1+g(x)) \in B$, and $h(y) = y \notin B$. Thus $h(x) \neq h(y)$, so this case is impossible.

Case 4 ($x \notin B$, $y \in B$): As in case 3, this case cannot happen.

So we have that $h(x) = h(y) \Rightarrow x = y$. Thus $h$ is injective.

Now we want to show surjectivity. Let $b \in A - f(1)$. We want to show that there exists an $a \in A$ such that $h(a) = b$. There are a couple cases:

Case 1 ($b \notin B$): Set $a = b$. Then $h(a) = h(b) = b$.

Case 2 ($b \in B$): Then $b = f(n)$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, since $f$ is bijective. Further, $n > 1$ since $b \in A - f(1)$. We have $g(a) = n-1$ for some $a \in B$, since $g$ bijective. Then $h(a) = f(n) = b$.

Thus $h$ is surjective. Since $h$ is both injective and surjective, it is bijective.

Comment: I am confused about the surjective part. can i ask you why you wrote $b \notin B$ and $b \in B$? instead of using a?

Comment: @Meer I started with $b$ and wanted to find an $a$ such that $h(a) = b$. Since I started with $b$, it was useful to case over $b \in B$ and $b \notin B$ since the nature of the corresponding $a$ value depended on it.

Answer (score 0):

$h$ is the identity on $A - B$, so we may assume w.l.o.g. that $A = B$.

Note that $\phi : \mathbf{N} \rightarrow \mathbf{N}_{> 1}, x \mapsto x + 1$ is a bijection. So 
$a \mapsto g(a) \mapsto g(a) + 1$ is a bijection from $\mathbf{N}$ to $\mathbf{N}_{> 1}$ (composition of bijections is again a bijection). Composing with $f$, we get the result.